# Upload/Download uint8array with Angularjs/Spring

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, uint8array

I have a Spring application using Angularjs for the frontend.

On the frontend, i read a file that i encode using Openpgpjs. After the encryption process, i get a Uint8Array object i want to save to the database.

```
// encoded_file is the Uint8Array
var file = new File(encoded_file, "my_image.png",{type:"image/png", lastModified:new Date()})

FileService.uploadFile(file).then(function(fileObject){
    console.log(fileObject); 
}).catch(function(error){
    toastrService.error(error, "Failed to upload file"); 
});


this.uploadFile=  function (file) {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', file);
    fd.append('auth', true);
    
    $http.post('/files/upload', fd, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
    }).then(function (response) {
        if (response.data && response.data.result){
            defer.resolve(response.data.entry);
        } else if(response.data) {
            defer.reject(response.data.message);
        } else {
            defer.reject();
        }
    }, function (error) {
        defer.reject(error);
    });
    
    return defer.promise;
};
```

The request is received by the server as follow as save the binary data in the DB

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/upload")
public String uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,@RequestParam("auth") Optional<Boolean> auth) throws Exception {
       // save file.getBytes() in the DB and return a uniqueID to the file
}
```

The file is made accessible in my app through the url /files/raw/id

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/raw/{fileId}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody byte[] getRawFile(@PathVariable String fileId, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    File f = fileService.getFile(fileId);
    if (f == null) {
        return null;
    }

    return fileService.getFileContent(f);

}
```

I have the following function to download the file

```
this.downloadFile=  function (guid) {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    var config = { responseType: 'arraybuffer' };
    $http.get('/files/raw/'+guid, config).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response)
        if (response && response.data){

           defer.resolve(response.data); 
        } else {
            defer.reject();
        }
    }, function (error) {
        defer.reject(error);
    });
    
    return defer.promise;
};
```

The problem is that Uint8array i get when downloading the file is different from the one i uploaded.
If i change the responseType as text. The number are matching the uint8array i uploaded but how can i get right ?

Comment: There is no need to manufacture a promise with `$q.defer` when the `$http` service already returns a promise.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

I changed the upload file code as follow :

```
// encoded_file is the Uint8Array
 var blob = new Blob([encoded_file.buffer], {type: $file.type});
 var file = new File([blob], $file.name);

FileService.uploadFile(file).then(function(fileObject){
    console.log(fileObject); 
}).catch(function(error){
    toastrService.error(error, "Failed to upload file"); 
});
```

and the download function as follow :

```
var fileReader = new FileReader();
fileReader.onload = function(event) {
      arrayBuffer = event.target.result;
};
fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file.data);
fileReader.onloadend = function (e) { 
     var data = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer) 
                    
}
```